# Normal Map Cycles Baking Help

Tags: cycles-render-engine, unity, normal-map

I baked a normal map in cycles with a method I found on youtube where you select the high poly (sculpted) version > then the low poly (non-sculpted) version > then bake with selected to active checked.

This gave me a nice normal map where all my sculpting showed up nicely on my low poly version. HOWEVER, it completed ignored my painted texture on my low poly object. I painted some wood tiles and figured when I baked it would recognize it and add some bump map action however it did not. How would I go about baking my sculpting from my high poly to my low poly version AND my low poly painted texture all onto one normal map image?

I’m creating this object for Unity so I kind of need it to all be on one normal map, thanks for the help.

This is my current node setup. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Plug your texture image into the displacement shocket on the material output node. You can add a (converter>>math>>multiply) node between them to adjust the strenght.

Edit.
Excuse me. I forgot that the "selected to active" means the active doesn't count, just the selected. So what you can do, duplicate the lowpoly object, than select all three model. This method gives much better result with Blender render.

Comment: Check my edit, I added some more info. I tried connecting the alpha on the left to the material output however still got the same result. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you link me a tutorial that includes the baking of a normal map including the high + low poly method + the paint? I have spent the last 3 days looking and still have not found anything. The only tutorials I can find online include the high to low poly sculpt bake method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you add a displacement texture to your high poly model then the Cycles Engine will bake that out along with the tangent normals. You may need to increase sub-surf/multi-res modifier up to level six to get a good bake. Also, you should bake your painted texture from your high-poly to your low poly so that they match.

Remember, you need a displacement node between your image texture and your material output. I have had the best results using a displacement normal map made from the diffuse texture using a normal map filter in Gimp.